# Detect C/C++ preprocessor abuse that leads to huge expanded code sizes

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am looking for a way to detect or mitigate C++ source that, when preprocessed, expands into huge sizes, so that GCC runs out of memory.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    #define A30 cout << "hello world";
    #define A29 if (1) { A30 } else { A30 }
    #define A28 if (0) { A29 } else { A29 }
    // ... you get the idea ... 
    #define A1 if (1) { A2 } else { A2 }
    #define A0 if (0) { A1 } else { A1 }
    A0
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this program should generate a huge, syntactically correct if-else tree (works with smaller versions; say, up to A10); if executed, it trivially prints one of the 2^30 "hello world" strings within that tree. However, attempting compilation on an 8GB machine causes unresponsive behaviour and (after a while) the following error to be displayed:

```
internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
A0
^
```

Is it possible to limit pre-processor expansion in the above case using GCC 4.9.x, or to otherwise avoid crashing with such programs?

Comment: While intriguing, have you found a real-world example of this actually being an issue? I feel like if your macros are this convoluted you're doing something wrong elsewhere...

Comment: @Qix  have not tested it against online compilers (e.g.: programming contests), but have reason to think it may affect some; I assume I am not the first to think of it though, and some C grey-beard will know an obscure GCC flag to stop it on its tracks.

Comment: I mean is there a _real world program_ that is generating such intense code for this to _really_ be an issue?

Comment: @Qix no; I am unaware of any honest code being this convoluted. However, there is such a thing as dishonest code and denial-of-service.

Comment: valid, though generally servers would just detect the compiler crashed and relay that to the user. Those compilers are usually sandboxed pretty well; I can't imagine it being a DOS threat. I doubt there's a piece of dishonest code out there that would actually cause this either, and if there is, the simple solution is _don't use it_.

Comment: Parts of Boost use macros that are nested much deeper than this (mostly to emulate variadic templates for pre-C++11 compilers, but not only), albeit not branching at every level like this. And then there's [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html). A limit that doesn't break real-world code would have to be something along the lines of "preprocessor: don't generate more than x MB of sourcecode."

Comment: I`m not sure about gcc, but in Linux you can limit virtual memory for some process with ulimit:

    (ulimit -v 16777216; gcc main.c)

In visual studio you can affect stack size(typical using for deep reqursion) using pragma:

    #pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:16777216")

Comment: "Segmentation Fault" pretty much tells us what happens: `malloc` fails, returns a null pointer, and GCC fails to check the return value of `malloc` in that path. Understandable, since GCC was historically written in C not C++. The equivalent C++ error would be an uncaught `std::bad_alloc` (C++ doesn't magically give you unlimited memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do what you are trying to achieve with a simple gcc command.
A way around it could be too add some extra steps into your build system, to see if a commit increased the code base by a certain percentage.

You have an option (-E) in gcc that outputs the code after the pre-processor step.

If you have a build at commit 1, you could save the number of lines at that commit, running gcc with -E, and doing a "wc -l" on its output.

At commit 2, before building, you do the same, and check that the number of lines hasn't increased by a threshold that you defined (10%, 20%?)

Comment: I believe that this (and @POTEMKINDX's answer using ulimit and VS pragmas) are the only workable approaches, even if they are not gcc-only. I will accept this answer if nothing better comes along within the next few days.